# ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)

Tags: python, ssl, gmail, imap

I recently attempted to make a script that would do something when it received a text from me, so I ran the script below on a "while True:" loop, and everything worked fine, as it retrieved my texts. But after a while of requests, it would give me the error "ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)" If anyone knows how I can fix this, it would be much appreciated even if it is a simple mistake on my behalf. Thanks!

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('example@gmail.com', 'passexample')
mail.list()
mail.select("inbox")

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split() 
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] 

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")

raw_email = data[0][1] 

email = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: wich python version? wich OP? windows? linux? IOS? every data you can provide would be helpful

Comment: You aren't showing a loop... How often are you hitting the service? Do you have a decent sleep in there? `gmail` may just be kicking you out from time to time and you can catch the error and try again. I'm not sure if you are re-logging on each time you check email but this seems like its just a case of handling errors and throttling your polls.

Comment: Show the full code with loop included so that we may understand the problem at hand.

Comment: @tdelaney I figured it out, I didn't have a timer in place.